# Bugged switch after calling hidegui()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I refactor the generator code and came across a problem. I suspect hidegui () causes this error, although I'm not sure, especially since I do not know how to fix it. Anyway, I click on a particular button on the page, it calls a message box with properly enabled / disabled inputboxes (I call this switch and the parameter enabled). Everything until that moment works ok. The problem occurs when you click X (close the message box) and call up the hidegui () function. I do not know, maybe in the wrong place I settled it?

```js
var overlay = $("#overlay");
var message = $("#message");

/* This function shows message-box */

function showGUI(enabled) {

  overlay.css("display", "block");

  /* Specifies which inputs are to be active after callback */

  switch (enabled) {
    case "add-box":
      $('#param1, #color, #color2, #param7, #param8, #param9').prop('disabled', true);
      break;

    case "other-box":
      $('#param1, #color, #color2, #param7, #param8, #param9').prop('disabled', true);
      break;

    case "section-box":
      $('#param6, #param9').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#param6-form, .success').remove();
      break;

    case "gallery-box":
      $('#param1, #param2, #param3, #color, #color2, #param7, #param8').prop('disabled', true);
      break;
  }
}

function hideGUI() {
  overlay.css("display", "none");
}

$(".fa-times").on("click", function() {
  hideGUI();
});

/* Parameters of inputs in message-box */

function params(type) {

  param1 = $("#param1").val();
  param2 = $("#param2").val();
  param3 = $("#param3").val();
  param4 = $("#color").val();
  param5 = $("#color2").val();
  param6 = $("#param6").val();
  param7 = $("#param7").val();
  param8 = $("#param8").val();

  switch (type) {
    case "img":
      $("#additional-box").append('<img src="' + param6 + '" style="width: ' + param2 + 'px; height: ' + param3 + 'px;">');
      break;

    case "otherimg":
      $("#other-photos").append('<img src="' + param6 + '" style="width: ' + param2 + 'px; height: ' + param3 + 'px;">');
      break;

    case "section":

      $("#new_section").append('<div class="section" style="width: ' + param2 + 'px;"><p style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px; margin-bottom: 0;">' + param1 + '</p><div class="section-content" style=" height:' + param3 + 'px; background: ' + param4 + '; color: ' + param5 + ';"></div></div>');
      for (count = 0; count < param8; count++) {
        $(".section-content").append('<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Sample text" style="width: ' + param7 + '" />');
      }

      break;

    case "gallery":
      $("#gallery").append('<img src="' + param6 + '" style="width: 100%;"/>');
      break;
  }

  if (param2 < 1180) {
    $(".section").css("float", "left");
  }

}

/* Sample button calling functions */

$("#add_section").on("click", function() {

  showGUI('section-box');

  $("#add-params").on("click", function() {
    params("section");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay">
<div id="message">
<div id="message-content">
<p id="m-title">Parameters <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Section title" name="param1" id="param1" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Element width" name="param2" id="param2" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Element height" name="param3" id="param3" />
<p class="dropdown">Choose element color <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></i></p>
<div id="colorpicker"></div>
<input type="text" id="color" name="param4" value="#123456" />
<p class="dropdown">Text color <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></i></p>
<div id="colorpicker2"></div>
<input type="text" id="color2" name="param5" value="#123456" />
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
<a href="upload.php" target="_blank" id="uploader">Go to uploader <i style="margin-left: 5px;" class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter source" name="param6" id="param6" />
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter input width" name="param7" id="param7" />

<div style="position: relative;">
<input type="text" placeholder="Amount of inputs" value="" id="param8" name="param8" />
<button type="button" class="count-field plus"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="count-field minus"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Image alt" name="param9" id="param9"/>


<button type="button" id="add-params">Add to template</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  
<div id="new_section">
<div id="default-section">Default section</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_section">Add new section</button>
```

Comment: Share the relevant HTML too

Comment: yes please show the HTML.

Comment: done guys, code updated

Comment: `pokaz is not defined` Share the working code and take us through on what is not working.

Comment: Excuse me, I've translated the names of variables from my language into English so that you understand the code more or less. I've improved.

Comment: I don't see the f-a times being declared on a clickable object.

Answer (score 0):

I only see fa-times being declared on the i Object. Try adding the class to the button and see if that doesn't resolve it.